# I am facing an issue in Click Once deployment of applications (WPF application using dot net frame work 4.5)

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I am getting a weird error while trying to  publish click once application. 
The set up is generated but  when i launch the set up it says:

```
Application cannot be started contact the application vendor.
```

i Checked the log file, it  says:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range
```

Here are some error line details:

```
ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [7/18/2014 9:49:13 PM] System.ArgumentException
    - Value does not fall within the expected range.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.LockApplicationPath(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionAppId ApId, IntPtr& Cookie)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.PatchFiles(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

I tried various suggested remedies like

1) changing the build target to x86

2) rebooting

In my Wpf application i have metro apps dll , a third party xaml ui frame work.

While generating the setup in the download prerequsites i  net 4.5 framework  i selected download from component vendors location option.

The Publish path i am setting in my local folder, as

```
\\CLBBLR--5030\e$\folder\
```

I am trying to publish my applicaton in the said folder, install the set up in c drive for testing purpose.

Is there any thing wrong in this, please help.

Comment: This means that the web installer cannot find the folder in which you have placed the deployed files. What appears to me is that you are trying to install without using IIS (which i recommend), if that's your case you can check if you folder is shared for everyone and if your firewall have the port 80 rule.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more specific. All of the information that it contains is available in the tags, and if you take that out the text you've used explains nothing about the actual issue. (It leaves "I am facing an issue", which is void of any information; clearly you're "facing an issue", or you wouldn't be asking a question here.) It also doesn't have anything relevant for use by future users of this site when they find it in a search result. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Guilherme,  i don't need the IIS and  port 80 information because the iam using unc file share path to publish my application , and the path i have published is my local path in my system which is accessible, the path where i have installed mu set up application is also in my local system, naturally there should be no problems in accessing my published path, once this works fine , i will try to to put it in Network shared path.